# get the data attribute from selected combox box jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('.tmp-class').change(function() {
        $('.tmp-class option:selected').each(function() {
            console.log($('.tmp-class').data('type'));
        })
    })
```

How can I get the selected combo box data attributes?
For more details, [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z47Fk/4/).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z47Fk/6/ hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each `$(this)` refers to `option` and you need `select` not `option`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/z47Fk/5/)**

```
 console.log($(this).parent().data('type'));
```

You probably do not need `each()` here, as the selected `option` is not required to get the `data` attribute of the `select`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/z47Fk/7/)**

```
$(function() {
    $('.tmp-class').change(function() {
        console.log($(this).data('type'));
    });   
})
```